# Track a particular row of a table of webclient page which has no unique id and this table keeps populating datas concurrently

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, automation

I'm working with web client-GUI-automation testing tool development using selenium-x path-css.

With this webclient, it has a panel area at the lower panel.
Within this panel is a table which has no unique id for its row.

Scenario: When I add a VM through webclient-GUI,  on clicking finish button, this lower panel area's table list at its first row that the task has started with

td: taskname, date, target  in its row[1] of a table.

In this case if a single task is happening, then this table would have only one row.

So that i can check as
   `tr[1]td[1] = "Create_Vm"` and confirm that the task has started.

But if multiple VM's say:3(vm1,vm2, vm3) are created concurrently, then the table would have

`tr[1]td[1]`

`tr[2]td[1]`

`tr[3]td[1]`

- All to be create_vm.

My problem is how do I track a particular task say:vm2 using selenium-xpath-css as there is no unique id for table rowid?

Comment: Share `HTML` code for the same

Comment: You might want to show the html with screen shot for the same if possible.

Comment: By looking at the table, how would you know which VM you're tracking? Is it by the index of the row?

Comment: @becixb: perfect catch! thank a lot for ur question. Even visually, we cant identify to which vm's creation the row belongs to. Let me check this point for a product bug.

Comment: @kanchana well if the vm's are displayed based on the time it started (from the top or from the bottom) then i've got an answer for you.

Comment: @becixb: Yes, of course it has start/completion-time column as                                      Start Time:
02/06/2017, 09:33:01

Completion Time
02/06/2017, 09:33:02

Comment: May I knw ur answer fr this case ?

Comment: @becixb:  Is it possible to use any pointer kind of concept for a randomtable like this so that we can point to a particular row even though table is populated with other tasks concurrently.?

Answer (score 0):

If let's say VM name is in the first column and your desired webelement is in the second column. You can do something like this.

```
//*[contains(text(),'vm2')]../../td[2]
```

Find out your column using contains text and then go to it's parent node. And then to your desired column.

Comment: My scenario is there are 3 columns taskname, target, status. Here TaskName is going to be "Create_vm" for creation task. so that for creating vm1, vm2, vm3 , it is going to show "create_vm" under taskname  and the vm name will not be displayed anywhere in the panel table. For eg:if thousand vms are created at same time vm1..vm1000, then all the taskname column will have only "create_vm" as data.

Comment: @kanchana is there any column which will have unique name ?

Comment: No :( that is my problem.....no column has unique data/id. But row-id happens to be there which is of 16 digits. but even that keeps changing wrt status. i.e.e,for  0% 5%.. 10% ..90%.. 100% completed.            row-id keeps changing for all these status of a particular row and remains constant only whenthe status is completed. Since i have to confirm that the task has started, this didnt help :(

Comment: @kanchana is this percentage appended at the end of the id? if so you can using //*[contains(id,'your_id')] and it will work.

Comment: @GaurangSingh: No, the entire id is changing and also to add, if a new task is started, then row-id of all the existing rows in bottom panel is also changing randomly.

Answer (score 0):

if the items are displayed in the order they are started, then do this:
`//table//tr[x+1]/td[1]`
if in reverse then:
`//table//tr[position()=last()+1-x]/td[1]`
where x is the vm number.